# Drone is not holding its position

Tags: quadcopters

I am working on a quadcopter drone, i am using s500 drone frame, pixhawk 2.4.7 flight controller,  dji 2212/920 bldc motor.
I am planning to use Raspi-4b to control the drone.
But before that, while implementing manual control with a RC, I am facing problems. The drone is not stable, it tends to move forward or rotate.

But while operating in altitude hold, it holds its height but tends to move in other direction.

I have made several tunning but still its not ok!

I do not know where the problem is! Is it with the flight controller?  Should i change it?

Will using code based control wit raspberry pi solve the porblem?

Sorry to bother you!

Answer (score 0):

Unless it's using a GPS receiver, the best a drone can manage is to stay approximately level. It's effectively frictionless, so any deviation from perfectly level (or any wind) will start it moving. Without a GPS, it can't detect motion, just acceleration.

Calibrating the accelerometers can help if it always drifts in the same direction (when there is no wind) but it's never perfect. For manual flight, you need to learn to make corrections and compensate for any wind.